# Displaying data in MPAndroid Line Chart

Tags: android-studio, mpandroidchart

I'm currently reading data from 7 sensors from bluetooth and displaying them with 7 lines in the chart. I managed to get the app working, for each data coming in, I implement the addEntry function below to update the chart and move the window along the x-axis to show the most updated data.

However, data transmission is at 100Hz, and the app will run for more than an hour, I found that the app freeze and might not be able to deal with this sometimes after running the app for a period of time, say 20 minutes. Given the large amount of data to deal with, I would like to just keep data for 10-15 seconds in the chart(i.e. even I scroll back to the beginning of the chart, it will just show 10-15s data). After some research, I just found the way
`mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();` to update data, which won't allow me to just display a selected part of the arraylist. Could any advice?

Thanks in advance.

```
        private void addEntry(){
        Log.d(TAG, "add Entry called");
        LineDataSet[] sensorSet = new LineDataSet[7];;
        if (mChart.getData() != null && mChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0){

            for (int k = 0; k<7; k++) {
                sensorSet[k] = (LineDataSet) mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(k);
                sensorSet[k].setValues(SensorData.getSensor()[k]);
            }

            mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();

            Log.d(TAG, "notified");
            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();

            mChart.setVisibleXRange(0,5000);
            int temp = mChart.getData().getEntryCount();
            Log.d(TAG, "Entry count: " + mChart.getData().getEntryCount());
            mChart.moveViewToX(mChart.getLineData().getXMax()-1000);
        }else{
            for (int k = 0; k<7; k++) {
                sensorSet[k] = createSet(k);
            }
            LineData data = new LineData(sensorSet);
            mChart.setData(data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if it helps ,but your correct you cant update the mp graph very quickly live. So limiting your live data to a fixed range makes sense. E.g. 100 data points. Therefore, for browsing the data you could have a filer function which works on your data set to view this data you want to see then update it to the graph.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, 
May I know more about the filer function you mentioned?

Comment: For having live data to a fixed range, is there a way to work around with the `sensorSet` ? As every time, I update the chart just by notifyDataSetChanged(), but I could not specify how much data (the window) I would like to display inside that sensorSet.

Comment: I kinda work around it. So I only show the last 60 entries to the graph. Done using a loop. So I store my live data to an SQL database. Then each second read the last 60 entries. To view what ever you want, filter the database and then display that.